# Creating a table with nested lists in Angulardart

Tags: html, dart, angular-dart

I'm trying to build a table representing a `List<List<int>>` in Angulardart.

This is the content of my template file:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#row of cells">
            <td *ngFor="#cell of row">
                <input type="number" #cell (keyup)="0"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the list is initialized like this:

```
class Grid {
    const GRID_SIZE = 9;
    List<List<int>> cells = new List(GRID_SIZE);

    Grid() {
        cells.forEach((x) => x = new List(GRID_SIZE));
    }
}
```

However, in the rendered HTML I only see 9 `<tr>` empty tags, with no `<td>`s inside.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in the grid initialization: the correct initialization code to have it filled with lists of zeroes is

```
cells.fillRange(0, cells.length, new List.filled(GRID_SIZE, 0));
```

The initialization code in the question only filled the main list with `GRID_SIZE` nulls.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this line:

```
cells.forEach((x) => x = new List(GRID_SIZE));
```

You are actually replacing x with a new value : you are not intervening inside x, but you created a new one.

```
List<String> myList = ['my', 'original', 'list'];

void yourForLoopFunctionSimulation( List<String> x ) {
  x = new List.filled(GRID_SIZE, 0);
  //you can work with the new x value here, but it won't change the argument that was passed to you
}

//if you run 
yourForLoopFunctionSimulation( myList );
print( myList ); // result : ['my', 'original', 'list'];
```